# Two categorical variables on same axis (not interconnected)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a newbie to R and there might be an obvious solution on this, but I have not found a solution by googling.

Is it possible, in ggplot or other charting package, to create a chart with two categorical variables (not hierarchical) on one axis, e.g. gender and agegroup as in the drawing attached.

[image: Example of wanted chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we could cook up some fake data.

```
## making some fake data
dat <- tibble(
  variable=factor(c(rep("Gender", 4), rep("Age Group", 8)), levels=c("Gender", "Age Group")), 
  levels = factor(rep(c("Male", "Female", "18-29", "30-49", "50-67", "68-80"), each=2), 
                  levels=c("Female", "Male", "68-80", "50-67", "30-49", "18-29")), 
  attr = rep(c("a1", "a2"), 6), 
  values = runif(12, 20, 70)
)
dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(levels) %>% 
  mutate(pct = values/sum(values))
dat
> dat
# # A tibble: 12 x 5
# # Groups:   levels [6]
#   variable  levels attr  values   pct
#   <fct>     <fct>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Gender    Male   a1      41.4 0.487
# 2 Gender    Male   a2      43.7 0.513
# 3 Gender    Female a1      35.8 0.534
# 4 Gender    Female a2      31.2 0.466
# 5 Age Group 18-29  a1      35.9 0.513
# 6 Age Group 18-29  a2      34.1 0.487
# 7 Age Group 30-49  a1      38.8 0.489
# 8 Age Group 30-49  a2      40.6 0.511
# 9 Age Group 50-67  a1      29.4 0.426
# 10 Age Group 50-67  a2      39.6 0.574
# 11 Age Group 68-80  a1      31.2 0.423
# 12 Age Group 68-80  a2      42.5 0.577
```

Then, we could make the plot with `ggplot()`.  Using `facet_grid()` will do what you want in terms of putting the different groups all on the y-axis.

```
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=levels, y=pct, fill=attr)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales="free")
```

[image]

One thing you might want to change is the height of each panel.  You can do this by manipulating the internals of the plot.  First, you have to get the grob.

```
gg <- ggplotGrob(g)
```

Then, you can define how high you want each panel to be.  Here, we'll say that the Gender panel should be 2 and the age should be 4.  These aren't in any particular units, they only represent the relative height of each.

```
h <- c(2,4)
```

Next, we need to find the place in the `heights` element of the `gg` object  to replace. We want to replace the `"1null"` elements with the heights that we've defined. Below, `height.inds` will be the observation numbers of the `gg$heights` element we need to replace.

```
height.inds <- grep("1null", gg$heights)
```

Next, we can replace the appropriate elements with our new heights

```
gg$heights[height.inds] <- unit(h, "null")
```

And re-draw the graph:

```
grid.draw(gg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to try to combine two plots instead of faceting.

### Data

```r
dat <- expand.grid(gender = c("A","B"), age = c("18-29","30-49","50-67","68-80"), reply = c("Y", "N"))
set.seed(42)
dat$value = sample(30, size= nrow(dat), replace = TRUE)
head(dat)
#   gender   age reply value
# 1      A 18-29     Y    17
# 2      B 18-29     Y    15
# 3      A 30-49     Y    24
# 4      B 30-49     Y     7
# 5      A 50-67     Y     4
# 6      B 50-67     Y    25
```

### Code

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
gg1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = gender, y = value, fill = reply)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
gg2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = age, y = value, fill = reply)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
gg1 / gg2
```

[image: ggplot2 bar plots, stacked]

There is much you can configure, see [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/index.html), [GH](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork), and its [complete docs](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/).